# how to convert specific string(dd-jun-yyyy hh:mm:ss) to date format in ssis

Tags: ssis, data-conversion

I have a problem trying to convert a String to DateTime (from DT-WSTR to TIMESTAMP)
usually I can do the conversion with just the DATA Conversion tool with a date format dd / mm / yyy hh: mm: ss
there I have a slightly different format to convert exp: 10-may-2013 10:05:00 and suddenly the conversion does not work
someone has an idea of how to do it?

Comment: What is the error message and what is the data source?

Comment: Error: Data conversion failed while converting column " flt_id_date" (27) to column "Copy of  flt_id_date" (6). The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".  the data source is a excel file

Comment: use (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)((SUBSTRING(your date,1,10)).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196671/how-do-i-format-dd-mmm-yy-values-in-flat-file-to-smalldatetime-during-data-impor

Comment: problem is i need all the informations of the date ( including the time) and casting to timestamp dosn't work with this format ( exp : 10-jun-2013 10:10:50)